# gdal ReadAsarray for vrt extremely slow

Tags: python, performance, mask, raster, gdal

I am trying to simply subtract two rasters and save the result in another raster. One of the input images is a tif-file, the other is a vrt-file. (Output is tif)

The files are very big, so I open them, divide them into tiles and run through each of them and then subtracting. **The problem is that it is extremely slow!**

```
import gdal
import numpy as np

rA = gdal.Open(raFileName)
rB = gdal.Open(rbFileName)

nodataA = rA.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
nodataB = rB.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()


raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(outputFileName, ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32,['COMPRESS=LZW','BigTIFF=YES'])

# tile size
trows = 5000
tcols = 5000
# number of tiles in output file   (ceil)
ntrows = (nrows-1)/trows+1
ntcols = (ncols-1)/tcols+1

# tiling because of memory problems
for r in range(ntrows):
    for c in range(ntcols):
        # number of rows/cols for tile r (in case of edge)
        rtrows = min(trows,nrows-r*trows)
        ctcols = min(tcols,ncols-c*tcols)

        # the data from the input files
        rA_arr = rA.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(c*tcols,r*trows,ctcols,rtrows)
        rB_arr = rB.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(c*tcols,r*trows,ctcols,rtrows)

        mask = np.logical_or(rA_arr==nodataA,rB_arr==nodataB)

        subtraction = rA_arr-rB_arr
        subtraction[mask] = nodata

        # writing this tile to the output raster
        rasterBand.WriteArray(subtraction,c*tcols,r*trows)            
        raster.FlushCache()
```

The rasters I am currently trying to subtract have 16*16 tiles (of 5000*5000 pxls) and after about two hours, it has only gone through 3 rows!

**Is there any way to increase performance??**

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do is investigate the layout of the files. A VRT by definition consists blocks of 128x128 pixels. For a Geotiff it can be anything.

You can check it with the `gdalinfo` utility or:

`rA.GetRasterBand(1).GetBlockSize()`

Also check this for the files underlying the VRT.

When reading chunks, its best to do it using the native blocksize or a multiple of it. So try to find the 'intersection' of all blocksizes you use. So if your VRT is 128x128, and your Geotiff has 512x1, reading in blocks of 512x128 (or a multiple) would be most efficient.

If this is not possible, it can help to set GDAL's cache as high as possible with:
`gdal.SetCacheMax(2**30)`

The value is in bytes, so `2**30` would be a GiB. This prevents unnecessary I/O to disk (which is slow).

What kind of VRT is it, a 'simple' mosaic/stack or does it contain all sorts of computations?

You can als run it once with twice the Geotiff as the input, to test if the its the VRT causing the delay (or the other way around).

If you have a lot of nodata, you could optimize your calculation a bit. But it seems so simple i don't think its anywhere close to being the bottleneck is this case.

edit:

#### Benchmark

I did a quick test where i deliberately read using an inefficient chunksize. Using a raster of 86400x43200 with a blocksize of 86400x1. I used your code to read the single raster (no writing). The MaxCache was set at 1MiB to avoid caching a lot, which would reduce the inefficiency.

Using blocks of 86400*1 it takes:

`1 loop, best of 3: 9.49 s per loop`

Using blocks of 5000*5000 it takes:

`1 loop, best of 3: 32.6 s per loop`

Comment: Didn't know the files have block sizes already, but since I make the tiff files myself, is there a way to define the block size when creating the raster? (Right now they are always x-dim*1)

Comment: You can add it to the creation options, just like you do with compression. `TILED=YES` creates tiles, by default of 256x256 (which is fine usually). You can set it manually by also adding `BLOCKXSIZE=n`. See the "creation options" on the Geotiff driver page:
http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html

Comment: How do I know which of the blocksizes to use? if I have e.g. 100000*1 in one image, and 4096*4096 in the other... 100000*4096 seems a little big...

Comment: That's probably too big indeed, ideally you would avoid it, if you have control over how those images were made. You could try how long it takes with `gdal_translate` to convert them to a TILED raster. Otheriwse use a blocksize of 100000x?, as large as possible. And iterate over the x-dimensions (cols) first. You now iterate over the rows first, meaning that for each row you read the entire 100000 in the background, over and over.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but here is a script I wrote based on Rutger's excellent answer. It somehow optimizes the tile size so that you read the fewest blocks possible. It's almost assuredly not the best you can do, but I noticed it vastly improved my runtimes when processing geo-rasters of size [1440000 560000]. There are two functions here: optimal_tile_size and split_raster_into_tiles. The latter will provide the coordinates of the (optimized w.r.t. blocksize) tiles for a given input raster object.

```
import numpy as np
import gdal

def split_raster_into_tiles(rast_obj, N, overlap=0, aspect=0):

    """
    Given an input raster object (created via gdal) and the number of tiles
    you wish to break it into, returns an Nx4 array of coordinates corresponding
    to the corners of boxes that tile the input. Tiles are created to minimize
    the number of blocks read from the raster file. An optional
    overlap value will adjust the tiles such that they each overlap by the 
    specified pixel amount.

    INPUTS:
        rast_obj - obj: gdal raster object created by gdal.Open()
               N - int: number of tiles to split raster into
         overlap - int: (optional) number of pixels each tile should overlap
 aspect - float or str: (optional) if set to 0, aspect is not considered. If 
                        set to 'use_raster', aspect of raster is respected.
                        Otherwise can provide an aspect = dx/dy.

    OUTPUTS:
           tiles - np array: Nx4 array where N is number of tiles and the four
                             columns correspond to: [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
    """

    # Get optimal tile size
    dx, dy = optimal_tile_size(rast_obj, N, aspect=aspect)

    ncols = rast_obj.RasterXSize
    nrows = rast_obj.RasterYSize

    # Generate nonoverlapping tile edge coordinates
    ulx = np.array([0])
    uly = np.array([0])
    while ulx[-1] < ncols:
        ulx = np.append(ulx, ulx[-1]+dx)
    while uly[-1] < nrows:
        uly = np.append(uly, uly[-1]+dy)

    # In case of overshoots, remove the last points and replace with raster extent
    ulx = ulx[:-1] 
    uly = uly[:-1]
    ulx = np.append(ulx, ncols)
    uly = np.append(uly, nrows)

    # Ensure final tile is large enough; if not, delete second-from-last point
    if ulx[-1] - ulx[-2] < 2*overlap:
       ulx = np.delete(ulx, -2)
    if uly[-1] - uly[-2] < 2*overlap:
       uly = np.delete(uly, -2)

    # Create tiles array where each row corresponds to [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
    tiles = np.empty(((len(ulx)-1)*(len(uly)-1),4), dtype=int)
    rowct = 0
    for i in np.arange(0,len(ulx[:-1])):
        for j in np.arange(0,len(uly[:-1])):
            tiles[rowct,0] = ulx[i]
            tiles[rowct,1] = ulx[i+1]
            tiles[rowct,2] = uly[j]
            tiles[rowct,3] = uly[j+1]
            rowct = rowct + 1

    # Adjust tiles for overlap
    if overlap > 0:
        tiles[tiles[:,0] > overlap, 0] = tiles[tiles[:,0] > overlap, 0] - overlap
        tiles[tiles[:,1] < (ncols - overlap), 1] =  tiles[tiles[:,1] < (ncols - overlap), 1] + overlap
        tiles[tiles[:,2] > overlap, 2] = tiles[tiles[:,2] > overlap, 2] - overlap
        tiles[tiles[:,3] < (nrows - overlap), 3] = tiles[tiles[:,3] < (nrows - overlap), 3] + overlap

    print('Tile size X, Y is {}, {}.'.format(dx, dy))

    return tiles


def optimal_tile_size(rast_obj, N, aspect=0):

    """
    Returns a tile size that optimizes reading a raster by considering the 
    blocksize of the raster. The raster is divided into (roughly) N tiles. If
    the shape of the tiles is unimportant (aspect=0), optimization 
    considers only the blocksize. If an aspect ratio is provided, optimization
    tries to respect it as much as possible.

    INPUTS:
        rast_obj - obj: gdal raster object created by gdal.Open()
               N - int: number of tiles to split raster into
         aspect  - float or str: (optional) - If no value is provided, the 
                   aspect ratio is set only by the blocksize. If aspect is set
                   to 'use_raster', aspect is obtained from the aspect of the
                   given raster. Optionally, an aspect may be provided where 
                   aspect = dx/dy.

    OUTPUTS:
              dx -  np.int: optimized number of columns of each tile
              dy -  np.int: optimized number of rows of each tile

    """

#    # If a vrt, try to get the underlying raster blocksize
#    filepath = rast_obj.GetDescription()
#    extension = filepath.split('.')[-1]
#    if extension == 'vrt':
#        sample_tif = rast_obj.GetFileList()[-1]
#        st = gdal.Open(sample_tif)
#        blocksize = st.GetRasterBand(1).GetBlockSize()
#    else:
#        blocksize = rast_obj.GetRasterBand(1).GetBlockSize()

    blocksize = rast_obj.GetRasterBand(1).GetBlockSize()

    ncols = rast_obj.RasterXSize
    nrows = rast_obj.RasterYSize

    # Compute ratios for sizing           
    totalpix = ncols * nrows
    pix_per_block = blocksize[0] * blocksize[1]
    pix_per_tile = totalpix / N

    if aspect == 0: # optimize tile size for fastest I/O

        n_blocks_per_tile = np.round(pix_per_tile / pix_per_block)

        if n_blocks_per_tile >= 1:
            # This assumes the larger dimension of the block size should be retained for sizing tiles
            if blocksize[0] > blocksize[1] or blocksize[0] == blocksize[1]:
                dx = blocksize[0]
                dy = np.round(pix_per_tile / dx)
                ndy = dy / nrows
                if ndy > 1.5:
                    dx = dx * np.round(ndy)
                dy = np.round((pix_per_tile / dx) / blocksize[1]) * blocksize[1]
                dy = np.min((dy, nrows))
                if dy == 0:
                    dy = blocksize[1]
            else: 
                dy = blocksize[1]
                dx = np.round(pix_per_tile / dy)
                ndx = dx / ncols
                if ndx > 1.5:
                    dy = dy * np.round(ndx)
                dx = np.round((pix_per_tile / dy) / blocksize[0]) * blocksize[0]
                dx = np.min((dx, ncols))
                if dx == 0:
                    dx = blocksize[0]

        else: 
            print('Block size is smaller than tile size; setting tile size to block size.')
            dy = blocksize[0]
            dx = blocksize[1]

    else: # optimize but respect the aspect ratio as much as possible

        if aspect == 'use_raster':
             aspect = ncols / nrows

        dya = np.round(np.sqrt(pix_per_tile / aspect))
        dxa = np.round(aspect * dya)

        dx = np.round(dxa / blocksize[0]) * blocksize[0]
        dx = np.min((dx, ncols))

        dy = np.round(dya / blocksize[1]) * blocksize[1]
        dy = np.min((dy, nrows))

        # Set dx,dy to blocksize if they're zero
        if dx == 0:
            dx = blocksize[0]
        if dy == 0:
            dy = blocksize[1]

    return dx, dy
```

As a quick benchmark, I tried tiling a 42000 x 36000 virtual raster (with some extra calculations) into 30 tiles. With optimization turned on, runtime was 120 seconds. Without it, runtime was 596 seconds. If you're going to tile large files, taking blocksize into account will be worth your while.